# Doorkeeper - How do I generate proper custom response upon succesful third party authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I have a problem with responding to the client properly. My relevant initlializer code looks like this:

```
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
    # Example implementation:
    #   User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)

    passed_params = {}
    %w(client_id redirect_uri state).each do |k|
      passed_params[k] = params[k]
    end

    User.find_by_id(session['user_id']) || redirect_to(new_ldap_login_path(passed_params))
  end
```

Here I pass the parameters to a form that does ask the user for LDAP credentials and goes to create method in the controller.

In the controller I perform LDAP authentication an upo succesful authentication I try to generate the response:

```
  if params[:client_id]
    client_app = Doorkeeper::Application.where(uid: params[:client_id]).first
    if client_app
      redirect_to (client_app.redirect_uri +
                   '?' +
                   { code: :what_is_supposed_to_be,
                     state: params[:state]
                   }.to_query)
```

That gives me the error:

> invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired,
>   revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization
>   request, or was issued to another client.

On the next login attempt the provider does not ask for the LDAP credentials and the login seems to work OK.

## guessing

Could this lead to the answer?

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/oauth/code_response.rb

How do I build the response that does not lead to the error?

## another clue

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/models/access_token_mixin.rb

## proposed solution

Create AccessToken and AccessGrant, making sure the token is the same in both records. For some strange reason AccessGrant is being saved with a different token. Why do I need to update the token on AccessGrant?

Once I have the token I redirect to redirect_uri with token and state in the query.

```
if authenticated
  if params[:client_id]
    client_app = Doorkeeper::Application.where(uid: params[:client_id]).first
    if client_app

  # taken from Doorkeeper model code
  #
  # Looking for not expired AccessToken record with a matching set of
  # scopes that belongs to specific Application and Resource Owner.
  # If it doesn't exists - then creates it.
  #
  # @param application [Doorkeeper::Application]
  #   Application instance
  # @param resource_owner_id [ActiveRecord::Base, Integer]
  #   Resource Owner model instance or it's ID
  # @param scopes [#to_s]
  #   set of scopes (any object that responds to `#to_s`)
  # @param expires_in [Integer]
  #   token lifetime in seconds
  # @param use_refresh_token [Boolean]
  #   whether to use the refresh token
  #
  # @return [Doorkeeper::AccessToken] existing record or a new one
  #



  code = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for(client_app,
                                                    @user.id,
                                                    nil,
                                                    7200,
                                                    true )

  grant = Doorkeeper::AccessGrant.create(resource_owner_id: @user.id,
                                         application_id: client_app.id,
                                         token: code.token,
                                         expires_in: 600,
                                         redirect_uri: client_app.redirect_uri,
                                         scopes: nil)
  # why do I have to update the token?
  grant.update(token: code.token)



  redirect_to (client_app.redirect_uri +
               '?' +
               { code: code.token,
                 state: params[:state]
               }.to_query)
```

Comment: If there is some piece of relevant code at the sites you have linked then please include it in your question. Don't expect people to sift through 300 lines of code to try to figure out what may or may not be relevant.

Comment: It has to wait until the 2nd January. If sifting through 300 lines of code is a problem, probably you do not know the answer. I am after the correct procedure for doing what I want. That is not documented. I was hoping that someone who knows doorkkeper gem inside out would know the answer. to me reading the code was relevant and the code works. The problem is I do not know if there is a better way of doing it. Particularly I am concerned about the need of updating the grant token.

Comment: I'm just trying to help you attract attention to this question by improving its quality; as it stands you've posted or linked to nearly 400 lines of code without having a clear problem statement. Frankly, I wouldn't begin trying to help you with the way it's currently written and I suspect others feel the same, given the lack of response and lack of votes. I hope you do find an answer, though.

Comment: As I said I have found the answer. The provider correctly handles logins from the client. What is the remaining part of the answer is the problem of having to update token in the access grant. That feels hacky. On one hand, it could help the community overall if there was a properly documented example for my scenario. Perhaps my question could lead to that. I am willing to answer further questions and clarify the matter. On the other hand, I have found the solution and if no one wants to go through the pain of clarification, we can just delete the question.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be dropped and rewritten from scratch?